# Security Error on webGL texImage2D function when using video from same domain as texture in ios 10.3?

Tags: javascript, ios, video, cors, webgl

I am having an issue in rendering 360 video to a canvas using webGL in ios 10.3
Similar symptoms of this issue point to the well known ios safari CORS issue that has yet to be fixed. The suggested workarounds revolve around reverse proxy, or hosting the video on the same domain.

I have the video on the same domain and am still receiving this issue: 
 `SecurityError (DOM Exception 18): The operation is insecure.`
Not only is the video on the same domain I also have this set on the server:

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

(However it makes little sense in this scenario that I should be having a CORS issue. Simply, the security error seems symptomatic of said issue).

This issue only occurs in ios 10.3 .   ios 10.2 can render my 360 video correctly. Also all modern desktop and Android browsers render the video fine (this. video in the code snippet below is just the video element source). Here is the line the error points to in safari web inspector:

```
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, this.video);
```

and here is location of the video in my `.html` file:

```
<video id="video" autoplay preload="auto" crossorigin="anonymous" style="display: none;" playsinline>
<source src="https://example.com/example360video.mp4?q=1" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I am cachebusting with the `q=1` Also here is the header retrieved from my video via a `curl -v`:

> < HTTP/1.1 200 OK < Date: Thu, 13 Apr 2017 15:51:51 GMT < Server:
>   Apache/2.2.31 < Last-Modified: Wed, 12 Apr 2017 15:07:57 GMT < ETag:
>   "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" < Accept-Ranges: bytes < Content-Length: 43720623 <
>   Cache-Control: max-age=2592000 < Expires: Sat, 13 May 2017 15:51:51
>   GMT < Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * < Connection: close <
>   Content-Type: video/mp4

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Can someone provide a solution? I have this webpage working on every platform except ios 10.3 and am completely confounded by this problem hindering further development.

Comment: Here are all the changes made to the webkit/ safari in ios 10.3:  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207617

Comment: It could be the case that an implicit conversion to a BLOB url like `blob:https://...` can make it CORS. Have you tried setting `src` on `video` tag directly? Another thing to check, is your html page on HTTPS too? Try using a relative URL. If you have access to Safari on a macbook, you can try running the code with CORS check disabled to make sure that's the cause of the problem. If `this.video` is stored on localstorage that can be the cause too.

Comment: Not doing a conversion to blob so don't think that could be it. I tried setting `src` tag inline but the same issue occurs, interestingly sometimes the canvas will load (maybe 1 in 150 loads --maybe something to do with video begin cached? Really not sure.) I am using HTTPS and CORS check is disabled, although I don't think it goes through to my ios 10.3 simulator I am using for testing purposes. Desktop Safari renders the video perfectly. What do you mean by your last sentence about `this.video` being stored on local storage being an issue?

Comment: Take a look at this [issue](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/51004). I'm not exactly sure why, but sometimes accessing the `localstorage` throws the same security exception. So, if the video content is buffered inside the `localstorage` that could be the cause too. Another thing that came to my mind: It could be in this iOS 10.3 they do some optimizations, and they don't load the video with `display: none`. You may try changing this to see if that's the case.